# Where in the navGrid section can I adjust the width of the Add Dialog Box

Tags: jqgrid

I have the following for my jqGrid navGrid section:

```
$("#loginList").jqGrid('navGrid', "#pager", { edit: false, add: true, del: false },
    {},{}       
);
```

I am not sure where I would put a value for the width of the add dialog box.
I tried:

```
$("#loginList").jqGrid('navGrid', "#pager", {width: 300},  { edit: false, add: true, del: false },
    {},{}       
);
```

But that did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may have your parameters out of order. 
When defining the navgrid the [parameters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#how_to_use) is as follows:

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager',{parameters},prmEdit, prmAdd, prmDel, prmSearch, prmView);
```

Since you are want to specify the parameters for the Add dialog you will want to define the width option as part of the `prmAdd` parameter.

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager',{parameters},prmEdit, { width: 300 }, prmDel, prmSearch, prmView);
```

Comment: Is parameters the same as where I have {edit: false, add: true, del: false} ?

Comment: yes {parameters} is where you define the overall navgrid parameters like edit: true, del: false, etc. Then you define the parameters for each type (ie add, edit) in there prm section (ie prmEdit, prmAdd).